# How to make system  automatically  mount encrypted device in  Linux

Tags: linux, mount, encryption

When I plug my external storage in , I need to  automatically mount it as an encrypted device.

How do I make this happen ?

Answer (score 5):

The issue with that is, for the system to automatically mount the encrypted device, the key for that device must be stored on the same system somewhere.  So, if your system is stolen, the key could be compromised.  If this is okay for you, then read on.

`udev` is the plug-and-play manager of Linux; anytime hardware is (dis)connected, it goes through `udev` and `udev` is responsible for putting it in the `/dev` directory somewhere or doing whatever needs to be done to make it recognized by the rest of Linux.   By digging into the depths of how `udev` works, you'll find it's possible to run a script when a USB mass storage device is connected.

Basically you'll need to go to /etc/udev/rules.d.  All files here are parsed by `udev` when it (re)starts, and these files can be used to fire off scripts when certain devices are connected.  Don't change anything you see here, but I added a `z60_usbmount.rules` with the following contents:

`KERNEL=="sd*", BUS=="usb", ACTION=="add",    RUN+="/etc/local/usbmountcheck udev add $kernel $parent"`

`KERNEL=="sd*",             ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/etc/local/usbmountcheck udev remove $kernel $parent"`

Thus when any external drive is attached via usb, that usbmountcheck script will run, with all the information `udev` gives up about the device.

The `usbmountcheck` script is a bit complicated, because you want to uniquely identify the drive, and the `sda`, `sdb`, etc. name, the `$kernel` name, won't do that.  Here's the bit of logic I included in my script to do that:

```
ACTION=$2
KVOL=$3
KVROOT=$4
# correlate volume name in /dev/disk/by-id with $KVOL, if we can
VNAME="`/bin/ls -l /dev/disk/by-id | /bin/grep $KVOL | /usr/bin/tr -s [[:space:]] ' ' | /usr/bin/cut -f 9 -d ' '`"
if [ "$?" != 0 ]; then
 die "error in pipeline that tries to get volume name, return code $?"
 fi
```

At this point `$VNAME` will have the device name as identified by USB.  You can then test if it's a known encrypted volume, and script the appropriate commands to mount it.  You'll also have to script an umount handler to automatically cleanup after a disconnect.

There's a lot of dangers in writing udev scripts because if they fail it could prevent udev from working and recognizing further hardware changes.  Tread with caution.

Comment: I don't understand why you're looking for information under `/dev/disk`. Why not use `%c` and `%P`? If you need more information, it's available under `/sys`.

Comment: Well, $KVOL is something like `/dev/sda`, etc. But I would rather know the `/dev/disk/by-id` entry, as those are unqiue according to disk manufacturer and serial number. Knowing the `/dev/disk/by-id` entry lets check amongst a list of known volumes and apply the correct key.  Didn't know about `%c` or `%P`...